# HTML Canvas: draw image without anti-aliasing

Tags: javascript, canvas, antialiasing

I want to do pixel-true rendering of some images on my Canvas. Right now, I obtain the images through Javascript, so my images are `HTMLImageElement` instances. I can draw these on the  Canvas' rendering context with `drawImage`. However, this performs anti-aliasing on the image, which I don't want.

There appears to be a lower-level image manipulation method named `putImageData`, operating on `ImageData` objects. Does this method perform any anti-aliasing? If not, it's a fine candidate for what I'm looking for, but I haven't found out how I can convert or blit an `HTMLImageElement` to an `ImageData` instance.

Any advice would be welcome!

Edit: my original problem was solved, I accidentally had a coordinate that was fractional, which forces anti-aliasing. The conversion-to-image-data question still stands though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to convert an image into an ImageData object is to draw it to a canvas first, so you'll need to create a temporary canvas, draw the image on it, and get the image data from there.

```
function imageToImageData(image) {
     var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
     canvas.width = image.width;
     canvas.height = image.height;
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
     return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Note though, that the same-origin policy prevents you from calling getImageData if you draw an image from a different domain to the canvas, so **this will only work on images from the same domain as the document**. If you need to draw images from other domains, your only option is to call `drawImage` on the context for you main canvas directly, making sure there are no transformations that will affect the accuracy.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this might be the only way, but I'm still fighting with some inexplicable implementation issues.